# If I use DejaDup to backup to alternating destinations, will its incremental features still work?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

The use case is this: I have two USB hard drives. Suppose one lives off-site, and another I keep at my desk. It's likely that one disk will get daily backups, the other weekly or monthly.

If I alternate which hard drive I'm backing up to, is DejaDup smart enough to make them both proper incremental backups? That is to say, if I create ~/foo.txt, then backup to hard drive #1, and then backup to hard drive #2, will backup #2 have the file, or will DejaDup decide it already backed up that file and doesn't need to again?

In other words, is it safe to change the backup destination in DejaDup as a means of backing up to multiple places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, backup #2 will have the file and things will work like you expect.

However!  Note that Deja Dup uniquely identifies the USB drive by filesystem ID so you can't "trick" it in some fashion by merely swapping disks.  You will actually have to change your backup location in your system settings to switch which disk Deja Dup uses.